# Aggregate production planning

Tags: optimization, reference-request

I'm looking for an optimization model about production planning that takes the following into consideration:

- Single site
- Multi products
- One machine/resource
- Sequence-dependent
- Fixed batch size
- Set-up times
- No back orders
- Capacity limitations

I understand that no finished model takes all this into consideration. I have looked at some lot-sizing problem, but the batch size is not adjustable in my case. I have looked through the following references:

Wolsey, L.,Pochet Y. (2006). *Production Planning by Mixed Integer Programming*. Springer Seriers in Operations Research and Financial Engineering. ISBN: 978-0387-29959-4

Trigeiro, W., Thomas, L. and McClain, J. (1989). *Capacitated Lot Sizing with Setup Times.* Management Science, 35(3), pp.353-366.

Voß, S., 2006. *Introduction To Computational Optimization Models For Production Planning In A Supply Chain*. Springer.

Can you guys point me in the right direction regarding references or key-words?

Answer (score 3):

The last reference you mentioned is one of the nice books (specifically, in an algebraic modelling language). I would like to add other good references like:

- [Scheduling in Supply Chains Using Mixed Integer Programming](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118029114) by Tadeusz Sawik.
- [Planning Stability in Material Requirements Planning Systems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540430155) by Heisig, Gerald.
- [Planning and Scheduling in Manufacturing and Services](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441909091) by  Pinedo, Michael.